# How to deal with failure to solve nonlinear equations during simulation in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I build a model of solar power plant with the Rankine cycle in Dymola, even though the initialization works fine, but at the time of 2840s, there is a failure to solve the nonlinear equations which leads the simulation to stop.
As shown in the following screenshot, Dymola recommends giving better start values, but it doesn't make any sense, because the failure happens during the simulation instead of initialization. And with better start values, the situation doesn't improve at all.
My question is :
How should I deal with the failure to solve nonlinear equations during simulation?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The error message indicates that the solver was not able to find a solution to a nonlinear system of equations in your model. This could mean either that there is no solution to the system or just that the solver is not able to find it.
The first easy steps would be to try a lower tolerance in simulation settings. And to use another solver that might suit better for your problem. Dassl can handle nonlinear systems quite well. If these steps won't work it might be that there just isn't a solution to your problem and you made a wrong assumption or accidentially have a wrong parameter somewhere.

Comment: And the tools available in Simulation Analysis will help finding what variables are causing the difficulties.

Comment: @DagB even I could find the variable that causes the difficulties, it is often hard to know which equation that causes the problems, in Dymola 2021, Simulation Analysis indeed shows the index matrix of the system equations, but doesn’t show detailed equations.